# Parse value as int in HLC files

Tags: configuration, scheduling, nomad, hcl

I am writing the template for a parametrized HashiCorp Nomad job. One of its parameters is `priority`, which is supposed to be an integer between 0 and 100.

Like other tools, Nomad supports [variable interpolation](https://www.nomadproject.io/docs/runtime/interpolation.html), so that a variable can be defined at some point and later referenced. Nomad also allows to define "meta" variables, which are passed at runtime and can be used within the HLC file.

What I'm trying to do looks as follows:

```
job "my-job" {
    parametrized {
        meta_required = ["TASK_PRIORITY"]
    }
    priority = "${NOMAD_META_TASK_PRIORITY}"
    ...
}
```

The only way I have found to read those variables are within strings. Since the `priority`  stanza expects an integer, the following error is thrown:

```
error parsing 'job': 1 error(s) decoding: * cannot parse 'Priority' as int: strconv.ParseInt: parsing "${NOMAD_META_TASK_PRIORITY}": invalid syntax
```

Is there any way to "cast" the string to an integer? Or, alternatively, is there any other way of referencing the variable that would work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up raising an issue on Github. Their response is that it's not yet possible to interpolate the `priority` field. [See issue](https://github.com/hashicorp/nomad/issues/6381).